# Where is the location of application shortcuts in Gnome?

Tags: gnome, gnome-panel, ubuntu-gnome

For shortcuts in the `Applications` drop-down Menu and on the title bar of the Gnome Desktop, where is the path to their directories?

Comment: For the benefit of a comprehensive understanding and an organic yet simple description on how desktop files work and where they should be placed, see the Gnome Developers website at:
https://developer.gnome.org/integration-guide/stable/desktop-files.html.en
Hope this helps!

Comment: That is a helpful resource, but seems to have been moved to: https://developer-old.gnome.org/integration-guide/stable/desktop-files.html.en

Answer (score 68, accepted):

You are looking for the `.desktop` files, which are located in `/usr/share/applications` (or sometimes `/usr/local/share/applications`).

Some applications may place these files in `~/.local/share/applications` instead.

Comment: I saw some duplications in that folder. I guess they are the shortcuts in the `Applications` menu? How about the shortcuts on the titlebar? I didn't see them in `/usr/share/applications`

Comment: What titlebar we're talking about ? The top black bar ?  Can you give example of application you're referring to ?

Comment: @Lee Are you referring to the tray icons, such as the bluetooth icon or the speaker volume icon?

Comment: @CharlesGreen yes, they are included on the title bar. I'm using `gnome-session-flashback`, not `unity`.

Comment: @Serg On the top of the Desktop, where there is `Applications` menu, custommed application shortcuts and applet indicators such as the icons of dropbox, input method, time clock and system menu.

Comment: Those may vary. If that's an external application like dropbox - it has .desktop file as well in `/usr/share/applicaitons/` folder. If that's something built in like clock or input method - that's built into the gnome, likely won't have a shortcut.

Answer (score 55):

1. **Most apps:**
   /usr/share/applications/
2. **Some apps:**
   /usr/local/share/applications
3. **Some other apps:**
   ~/.local/share/applications/
4. **Installed with Snap apps:**
   /var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications/
5. **Installed with Flatpak apps:**
   /var/lib/flatpak/exports/share/applications/
6. **Installed with Wine apps:**
   ~/.local/share/applications/wine/Programs/

Answer (score 9):

Your own shortcuts can also be placed in `~/.local/share/applications`.

Comment: This would be better off as an edit to the existing answer.  (you also get additional reputation for editing existing answers here)

Comment: @DavidCulbreth: Posting questions, posting answers and editing answers are rep 1 privileges.  Posting comments needs higher rep.