# Viber appears huge - Kubuntu 16.04

Tags: kubuntu, viber

I have made a clean installation of Kubuntu 16.04 and played around with the font sizes and other settings (such as the fonts DPI, but I tried resetting it...) to make it more to my liking and everything works fine, except for Viber; It is huge! It takes up pretty much the whole screen and cannot be resized to a smaller window (as the interface itself appears enormous, the letters, everything). Any other program I've used is completely normal...

Answer (score 59, accepted):

> > Just updated to lastet Viber version and it became huge.

The reason is that 1920x1080 px  on 13" screen has dpi of 166, what I have set in my xfce settings.
A lot of apps powered with electron or other custom magic treat dpi over 140 as "*retina*" and double rendering size.

Viber settings screen cannot go UI scaling under 100%, so you can do it manually.

### New solution (works for Viber >= v7.0)

Try running Viber from the terminal by specifying the `QT_SCALE_FACTOR` as follows:

> QT_SCALE_FACTOR=0.6 /opt/viber/Viber

As a permanent solution, ensure the following line is in place in the Viber starter shortcut file (.desktop):

> Exec=env QT_SCALE_FACTOR=0.6 /opt/viber/Viber

The Viber .desktop file is [usually located](https://askubuntu.com/questions/747118/where-is-the-location-of-application-shortcuts-in-gnome#747122) at `/usr/share/applications/viber.desktop`. A locally editable copy can be placed in `~/local/share/applications/`.

### Old solution (works for Viber < v7.0)

Install `sqlitebrowser` from official repo, use it to open `~/.ViberPC/config.db`

Go to table `CommonSettings` and modify `Value` of `ScalingRatio` to something under 1.0, I used 0.6.

Comment: BTW this works also on gnome gui if some one needs it.

Comment: that's awesome! works ubuntu 17.04 with unity and 1920x1080

Comment: seems to be not working any more, there is no ScalingRatio title and if created and set value to 0.6 nothing changes

Comment: @geotavros tried with Viber v7 and updated answer, try now

Comment: Confirmed the Viber v7 update. It crashes the Mate panel when updating the application launcher for some reason - but running from the terminal works like a charm, thanks!

Comment: @ModoLtunzher, thank you. It worked from terminal, but I struggled to get the .desktop file working. Eventually I did drag n drop of Viber icon from dash to desktop. Launched text editor and opened the Viber.desktop file from it. Then I had to add `env` keyword before the `QT_SCALE_FACTOR`. After that it worked

Comment: The new solution doesn't seem to work for me... It managed to work once and then when I closed the terminal window it reverted. Now once again it says 'QApplication: invalid style override passed, ignoring it.' If I force it with sudo viber goes into a constant Online Offline state and terminal spams 'Qt WebEngine ICU data not found at /opt/viber/resources. Trying parent directory...'  and 'qml: type="" '.....

Comment: @Kristóf if you run application from terminal, then it becomes parent process and when you close terminal window it also destroys child processes.
If you need to keep process, you better run it with ```/opt/Viber/Viber&```.
If you want to run viber froum your applications menu with correct scaling, edit Viber menu entry with corresponding editor for your DE and change it from ```/opet/Viber/Viber %U``` to ```env QT_SCALE_FACTOR=0.6 /opt/Viber/Viber %U``` and save

Comment: I see, but which file do I change? I can't seem to be able to open the opt/Viber/Viber file with a text editor. Is the .desktop file somewhere else?

Comment: Nevermind, I found the desktop file. I'll try to see if it works, thanks.

Comment: That was not worked for me on my Xenial Xubuntu, but the `QT_AUTO_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTOR=0` solved my problem. - http://blog.qt.io/blog/2016/01/26/high-dpi-support-in-qt-5-6/

Comment: @Kristof you have completed the answer thank you.

Comment: This doesn't work with the most recent version.

Comment: @SvetlanaBelkin I'm using version 10.3.0 and this still works. What version are you using?

Comment: 10.3.0. Strange.

Comment: You need to modify the line in the viber.desktop file and set the resolution to your screen, adjust the value, it can be any small like 0.5 or anything higher like 1.5:     "exec=env QT_SCALE_FACTOR=1.1 /opt/viber/Viber %u" 
There Viber.desktop files can be found at 2 places:
"/usr/share/applications/" and "/home/username/.local/share/applications"
When I edited the 1st file nothing happened. When I edited the .local file, it changed to correct resolution!

So: adjust QT_SCALE_FACTOR in "/home/username/.local/share/applications/Viber.desktop" to a good value.

Answer (score 20):

If you have double screen this is not good solution.

I prefer to set the environment variable `QT_AUTO_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTOR=0` with `env`.

For example:

```
env QT_AUTO_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTOR=0 /opt/viber/Viber
```

Comment: worked like a charm

Answer (score 8):

Or use sqlite3

```
$ sqlite3 ~/.ViberPC/config.db -interactive 'update CommonSettings set Value = 0.6 where Title = "ScalingRatio"'
```

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! This looks more like a (worthwhile) addition to the accepted answer and less like a self-contained answer. In such a case please suggest an edit to the post you want to improve instead of posting a partial answer. Thanks.

Comment: This answer is perfect - one-step solution !

Answer (score 4):

From Qt documentation:

> `QT_AUTO_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTOR [boolean]` enables automatic scaling, based on the pixel density of the monitor. This will not change the size of point sized fonts, since point is a physical unit of measure. Multiple screens may get different scale factors.

So setting this to false (zero) will not always solve the scaling problem. I had to change `QT_SCALE_FACTOR=0` to display Viber window normally:

```
env QT_SCALE_FACTOR=0 QT_AUTO_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTOR=0 /opt/viber/Viber
```

Comment: Thanks, this answer solves the issue for me, others didn't.

Answer (score 2):

**For Viber v7.0** and **>**

I create file

```
touch viber.desktop
```

in file write

```
 Exec=env QT_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTORS=0.6 /opt/viber/Viber
```

Then if I want start Viber -> use command in terminal

```
source viber.desktop
```

It's QT bug. I hope someone fix it.

Comment: That works for me!!! Thanks!