# Viber doesn't load anymore after upgrade to 6.5.5

Tags: qt, viber

Using Ubuntu 16.04 with all upgrades. Viber stopped loading after upgrade to latest version 6.5.5. 
Problem remained after clean reinstall of Ubuntu.

Below is the output of  `/opt/viber/Viber`

```
    /opt/viber/Viber
QSqlDatabasePrivate::removeDatabase: connection 'ConfigureDBConnection' is still in use, all queries will cease to work.
Qt WebEngine ICU data not found at /opt/viber/resources. Trying parent directory...
Qt WebEngine resources not found at /opt/viber/resources. Trying parent directory...
Qt WebEngine ICU data not found at /opt/viber/resources. Trying parent directory...
Qt WebEngine resources not found at /opt/viber/resources. Trying parent directory...
QXcbConnection: XCB error: 3 (BadWindow), sequence: 508, resource id: 54525979, major code: 2 (ChangeWindowAttributes), minor code: 0
QXcbConnection: XCB error: 3 (BadWindow), sequence: 509, resource id: 54525979, major code: 18 (ChangeProperty), minor code: 0
QXcbConnection: XCB error: 3 (BadWindow), sequence: 510, resource id: 54525979, major code: 18 (ChangeProperty), minor code: 0
QXcbConnection: XCB error: 3 (BadWindow), sequence: 511, resource id: 54525979, major code: 18 (ChangeProperty), minor code: 0
QXcbConnection: XCB error: 3 (BadWindow), sequence: 513, resource id: 54525979, major code: 18 (ChangeProperty), minor code: 0
QXcbConnection: XCB error: 3 (BadWindow), sequence: 514, resource id: 54525979, major code: 18 (ChangeProperty), minor code: 0
QXcbConnection: XCB error: 3 (BadWindow), sequence: 515, resource id: 54525979, major code: 18 (ChangeProperty), minor code: 0
QXcbConnection: XCB error: 3 (BadWindow), sequence: 519, resource id: 54525979, major code: 18 (ChangeProperty), minor code: 0
QXcbConnection: XCB error: 3 (BadWindow), sequence: 523, resource id: 54525979, major code: 2 (ChangeWindowAttributes), minor code: 0
    ................
```

Cannot make it work, cannot find previous version that worked.

Help will be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i had same issue- workaround , run it with param :

```
env QT_AUTO_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTOR=0 /opt/viber/Viber
```

From https://askubuntu.com/a/923652/706830

Comment: thanks!
It solved the problem!  Somehow I missed the post with the solution, as problem description didn't match with mine.

Comment: I can't make the latest version work under LXDE. Is it maybe that my screen resolutions is 1024x600