# Creating .desktop launcher with QT_SCALE_FACTOR

Tags: command-line, launcher, qt

I'm trying to create a launcher to replace this terminal command:

```
QT_SCALE_FACTOR=2 /home/cozza/V-PlaySDK/Tools/QtCreator/bin/qtcreator
```

I created the a .desktop

```
nano ~/.local/share/applications/VPlay.desktop
```

Added this

```
[Desktop Entry]
Comment="Launching VPLay"
Terminal=false
Name=VPlayScale
Exec=QT_SCALE_FACTOR=2 /home/cozza/V-PlaySDK/Tools/QtCreator/bin/qtcreator
Type=Application
Icon=/home/cozza/Qt/vplay-icon.png
```

Saved.

Then:

```
chmod +x '/home/cozza/.local/share/applications/VPlay.desktop'
```

When trying to launch I get error:

```
"There was an error launching the application."
```

It works without the QT_SCALE_FACTOR=2 at the start so it's clearly not supposed to go there but I don't know where else to place it.

How do I create a launcher with this preceding argument?

Thanks.

Comment: Try using `env` as described here: [Viber appears huge - Kubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/a/882742/178692)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The correct command in  `VPlay.desktop`

```
Exec=env QT_SCALE_FACTOR=2 /home/cozza/V-PlaySDK/Tools/QtCreator/bin/qtcreator
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this answer didn't work on my system: Exec=env QT_SCALE_FACTOR=2 snap run whatsdesk