# Viber appears huge

Tags: 18.04, viber

I installed Viber 7 on my laptop on Ubuntu 18.04, but it appears huge. I tried both the solutions (new and old) given [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/881679/viber-appears-huge-kubuntu-16-04) with no result. The new solution does not give anything at all in the terminal. The old one does not include any *ScalingRatio* in the *CommonSettings/Value*. I had to create it myself and try all the options given in "not null" and "null" combinations, but none of them worked.

As I am neither an IT nor a Linux specialist and not an English speaker, I would appreciate your help given in details and simple language so that I may understand exactly what I must do to solve this problem.

Comment: Why are you using Viber v7? I am using Viber v10.3 on Ubuntu 18.04 and the solution in the link you provided works perfectly for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can try start Viber in terminal using this command. If viber was installed using `snap`

```
QT_AUTO_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTOR=0 viber-mtd.viber
```